# $p^{10}+1$ is divisible by $125$

Tags: number-theory

Let be $p$ an arbitrary prime.

When $125$ divides $p^{10}+1$?

The two values I found are p=$7$ and p=$43$.

$7$ and $43$ are the only primes such that $10^{7}+333667$ is prime and $10^{43}+333667$ is prime.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg there is also $p=107$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg but $2^{10}+1=1025$ is not divisible by $125$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg     $2^{10}+1$ is divisible by $25$ but not by $125$

Comment: Yes, I saw it already.

Answer (score 1):

$a^{10}+1$ is divisible by $125$ iff $a \equiv 7,18,32,43,57,68,82,93,107,118
 \bmod 125$.

Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions implies that there infinitely many primes in each of these congruence classes.

Here are the smallest primes in each class:
$$
\begin{array}{r}
a & 7 & 18 & 32 & 43 & 57 & 68 & 82 & 93 & 107 & 118 \\ 
p & 7 & 643 & 157 & 43 & 307 & 193 & 457 & 593 & 107 & 743
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Can you tell me how you get all classes? Using a program we can't be sure that we have exhausted all classes.

Comment: @taritgoswami, I tested $a=0,1,\dots,124$. And yes this is enough because $a^{10}+1$ is a polynomial and every integer is congruent to one of these mod $125$.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of such primes for which $125$ divides $p^{10}+1$. Here are some of them - $7,43,107,157,193,$$257,\cdots $. Using this Python program below, you can generate more-

```
import math

def sieve(n):
    is_prime = [True] * (n+1)
    primes = [2]

    for p in range(3, n + 1, 2):
        if is_prime[p]:
            primes.append(p)

            for multiple in range(p * p, n + 1, p + p):
                is_prime[multiple] = False

    return primes

primeList=sieve(20000)  #change this if you want to try for some bigger number

classes=set()
for p in primeList:
  if((p**10+1)%125==0):
    print(p) 
    classes.add(p)
print(classes) #this will show you the primes modulo 125, for which the property holds
```

As stated also by @lhf, you will have $p\equiv 7,18,32,43,57,68,82,93,107,118\pmod{125}$, the set named `classes` will show you the congruence class modulo $125$.